# ArgumentError in Products#show , 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I doing a grocery website. Now i want to show the outletproduct details to product page and i have create a partial file which name as outletproductform.html.erb to put at the product show page. But it show the error to me, here is my code.

Product Controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

 def category
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
 end

 def index
  @products = Product.all
 end

 def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @outlet_product = OutletProduct.find(params[:id])
 end

 def new
  @product = Product.new
  @category = Category.all
 end

 def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  @category_id = Category.all
  if @product.save
   flash[:success] = "Succesful create!"
   redirect_to @product
 else
   render 'new'
 end
end

 private

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :quantity, :price,
                                  :category_id, :cost)
end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @product.name)%>

<%= render @product %>
<%= render @outletproductform %>
<div class="row">
 <aside class="col-md-4">
  <section class="stats">
   <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
  </section>
 <div>
   <%= link_to "Add to Outlet", new_outlet_product_path %>
   <%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path %>
   <%= link_to "Back to products", products_path %>
 </div>
 </aside>
</div>
```

_outletproductform.html.erb

```
<div>
 <table class="styled-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Outlet</th>
     <th>Quantity</th>
     <th>Selling Price</th>
     <th>Last Cost</th>

    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td><%= outlet_product.outlet.name %></td>
    <td><%= outlet_product.quantity %></td>
    <td><%= outlet_product.selling_price %></td>
    <td><%= outlet_product.last_cost %></td>
  </tr>

 </tbody>
</div>
```

OutletProduct migration table in schema

```
create_table "outlet_products", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "outlet_id"
t.integer "product_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.decimal "selling_price"
t.decimal "last_cost"
t.decimal "quantity"
```

end

[error show in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpLnE.png)

[error show in website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVy5D.png)

Comment: looks like you dont have the right partial? do you have a view thats something like *outlet/_form*? then you could do ```<%= render 'outlet/form %>```. Also you never define *@outletform*, which is why its nil

Comment: Hi, i have edit my question. I didn't have outlet/_form , i just have the _outletproductform file. Because this is in product controller here so i think maybe it won't have outlet/_form right?

Comment: Im not certain but if you pass an object to the *render* method it will try and find a corresponding view file. as it stands you are passing nil so that wont work. Its a little tough without knowing your folder structure but you could try ```<%= render 'outletproductform' %>```, that way it should look for a partial called *outletproductform* in the *products* view folder.

Comment: okay, i have try product/outletproductform and it can work, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you are passing *@outletproductform* to the *render* method, but since you havent defined it, its nil, hence the error.

this works on the previous line because you have a valid object for *@product* and the render method is looking for a corresponding view file.
(eg if you pass a list of products it will look for the *index.html.erb* view and so on)

Since you already have the right view file in the right location, *views/products/_outletproductform*, you just have to change this to be:

```rb
<%= render 'outletproductform' %>
```

Note that if you are looking for a partial that isnt located in the same folder (in this case *products*) you would need to reference the correct path, ie

```rb
<%= render 'some_model/some_partial' %>
```

[here is the layout and rendering guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: Good answer - another smaller which will blow up right after this is fixed error is `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path %>` which is should be  `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(@product) %>` .

Comment: Thanks Haumer for your answer and explanation about this question, really appreciate it.